# Converting lat/long into correct format

Tags: r

I have some data which looks like:

```
     long_bnk                 lat_bnk                  
[1,] "3<U+00B0> 52' 30.1\" W" "40<U+00B0> 44' 3.7\" N" 
[2,] "2<U+00B0> 44' 54.4\" E" "42<U+00B0> 7' 18.1\" N" 
[3,] NA                       NA                       
[4,] "2<U+00B0> 7' 54.2\" E"  "41<U+00B0> 31' 21.9\" N"
[5,] "0<U+00B0> 1' 54.5\" W"  "39<U+00B0> 58' 59.3\" N"
[6,] "3<U+00B0> 41' 15.5\" W" "40<U+00B0> 27' 47.2\" N"
```

I am trying to put the data into the correct lat/long format. I am running the following:

```
pts_bnk[pts_bnk==""] <- NA 
pts_bnk <- pts_bnk[complete.cases(pts_bnk),]
pts_bnk <- matrix(as.numeric(sp::char2dms(as.vector(pts_bnk), "°")), ncol=2)
```

However, I keep getting:

> Error in if (any(abs(object@deg) > 90)) return("abs(degree) > 90") :
>   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed In addition: Warning message: In
>   asMethod(object) : NAs introduced by coercion

Where am I going wrong in the conversion to the correct lat/long format?
Data:

```
pts_bnk <- structure(c("3<U+00B0> 52' 30.1\" W", "2<U+00B0> 44' 54.4\" E", 
NA, "2<U+00B0> 7' 54.2\" E", "0<U+00B0> 1' 54.5\" W", "3<U+00B0> 41' 15.5\" W", 
"40<U+00B0> 44' 3.7\" N", "42<U+00B0> 7' 18.1\" N", NA, "41<U+00B0> 31' 21.9\" N", 
"39<U+00B0> 58' 59.3\" N", "40<U+00B0> 27' 47.2\" N"), .Dim = c(6L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("long_bnk", "lat_bnk")))
```

EDIT:

Essentially I would like to plot the data using:

```
library(ggrepel)
library(ggmap)
register_google(key = "MyKey")
spain <- get_map("Spain", zoom = 6)
ggmap(spain, extent = "normal") +
geom_point()
```

EDIT 2:

The original data I had (which works) was the following:

```
dms_lat <- readLines(n=5)
1  40° 25' 35.8" N
2  40° 26' 28.4" N
3  40° 28' 39.8" N
4                 
5  38° 59' 15.0" N
dms_long <-readLines(n=5)
1   3° 41' 19.9" W
2   3° 47' 42.2" W
3   3° 41' 11.7" W
4                 
5   3° 55' 29.6" W
pts <- cbind(dms_long, dms_lat)
pts <- sub("^\\d+\\s+", "", pts)
pts[pts==""] <- NA
pts <- pts[complete.cases(pts),]
pts <- matrix(as.numeric(sp::char2dms(as.vector(pts), "°")), ncol=2)
library(rworldmap)
plot(subset(getMap(resolution = "low"), NAME=="Spain"))
points(pts[,1], pts[,2], col = "red", pch=3, cex = 0.6)
```

The current data I have (which does not work) is:

```
x <- structure(c("3<U+00B0> 52' 30.1\" W", "2<U+00B0> 44' 54.4\" E", 
NA, "2<U+00B0> 7' 54.2\" E", "0<U+00B0> 1' 54.5\" W", "3<U+00B0> 41' 15.5\" W", 
"40<U+00B0> 44' 3.7\" N", "42<U+00B0> 7' 18.1\" N", NA, "41<U+00B0> 31' 21.9\" N", 
"39<U+00B0> 58' 59.3\" N", "40<U+00B0> 27' 47.2\" N"), .Dim = c(6L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("long_bnk", "lat_bnk")))

x %>%
  data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(
    lat = sub("<U\\+00B0>", "\u00B0", lat_bnk),
    long = sub("<U\\+00B0>", "\u00B0", long_bnk)
  ) %>% 
  select(lat, long) %>% 
  drop_na()
```

I am trying to make this second data be equal to the first so it can be plotted using `ggmap()`.

Comment: You may need to replace the `<U+00B0>`

Comment: I am trying `sub("\\<[^\\]]*\\>", "", pts_long)` without much luck.

Comment: Do you need `char2dms(sub("(\\d+)<[^ ]+\\s*", "\\1d", c(pts_bnk)))`

Comment: I think so but I want to plot these points using `ggmap` and `geom_point()` where `geom_point()` takes an `x = lat`, `y = long` data type. I am not sure if it is possible with an object as `Forma class DMS`.

Comment: Appologies. I was hoping to get the data into the format where I can plot the data. What I have currently is: `x %>%
  head() %>% 
  mutate(
    lat = sub("(\\d+)<[^ ]+\\s*", "", Latitude),
    long = sub("(\\d+)<[^ ]+\\s*", "", Longitude)
  ) %>% 
  matrix(as.numeric(sp::char2dms(as.vector(x), "°")), ncol=2)`

Comment: Sorry, I don't have key to test your code.  May be somebody else would test it

Comment: Thanks, anyways!

Comment: I think I might be able to solve my issue... how can I change `"40<U+00B0> 44' 3.7\" N"`  to `"40° 44' 3.7\" N"`  - basically swap out the `<U+00B0>` for an `°`?

Comment: `gsub("<U\\+00B0>", "\u00B0", as.vector(pts_bnk))`

Comment: Also I believe you can substitute `<U+00b0>` with the letter `d` instead for using `char2dms`

Comment: I added an edit (EDIT 2) with some original data/ code that I managed to find and my current data / code. The original version works but my attempt now does not.

Comment: You can add `%>% mutate_all(~ as.numeric(sp::char2dms(., "°")))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me know if this works for you based on our comments:

```
library(rworldmap)
library(sp)
library(dplyr)

pts <- x %>%
  data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(
    lat = sub("<U\\+00B0>", "d", lat_bnk),
    long = sub("<U\\+00B0>", "d", long_bnk)
  ) %>% 
  select(lat, long) %>% 
  drop_na()

pts_long <- as.numeric(char2dms(pts[["long"]]))
pts_lat <- as.numeric(char2dms(pts[["lat"]]))

plot(subset(getMap(resolution = "low"), NAME=="Spain"))
points(pts_long, pts_lat, col = "red", pch=3, cex = 0.6)
```

Note that the `char2dms` is used as follows:

```
char2dms(from, chd = "d", chm = "'", chs = "\"")
```

where the default for degree character terminator is the letter `d` (an alternative to the degree symbol, if `chd` not specified).

[image: plot of Spain with points]

Using `ggmap` you can pass longitude and latitude in `geom_point`:

```
library(ggrepel)
library(ggmap)
library(ggthemes)

pts_data <- data.frame(pts_long, pts_lat)

# Note requires Google key
spain <- ggmap::get_map("Madrid, Spain", zoom = 6)
ggmap(spain, extent = "normal") +
  geom_point(data = pts_data, aes(x = pts_long, y = pts_lat)) +
  theme_map()
```

[image: using ggmap for plotting]

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect! How can I pass the `pts_long` and `pts_lat` to the `geom_point`. What I am trying to do is: `ggmap(spain, extent = "normal") +
  geom_point(aes(x = Long, y = Lat),
             data = pts, alpha = 1, size = 6, shape = 22, color = "black", stroke = 1)
` once I downloaded the map using `get_map` from  `ggmap`.

Answer (score 2):

We can add `mutate_at` at the end

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(
    lat = sub("<U\\+00B0>", "\u00B0", lat_bnk),
    long = sub("<U\\+00B0>", "\u00B0", long_bnk)
  ) %>% 
  select(lat, long) %>% 
  drop_na()%>% 
  mutate_at(vars(matches('^(lat|long)')), ~ as.numeric(sp::char2dms(., "°")))
```

Comment: I have an extra column in my data so `mutate_all` removes it. How can I use `mutate_at` to just mutate the `lat` and `long`. My current attempt is `mutate_at(vars(lat, long), funs(as.numeric(sp::char2dms(., "°"))))`

Comment: @user113156  As we have already created lat/long, then your attempt is very good